# SciFi book series about a group of future space marines with invisible camouflage, encountering a vicious alien force; one "Sgt Bass" character

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am trying to to remember a book series set in the future about a marine force sent to distant planets for various combat missions.  Along the way they encounter a vicious alien force.  The marines have camouflage that renders them invisible. I also recall one of the main characters named Sgt. Bass, or Master Sgt Bass.  I do not think it is by Ian Douglas.

Comment: Thanks FuzzyBoots.  I could not figure out how to send you a message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you be thinking of the *[Starfist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarFist_series)* series by David Sherman and Dan Cragg?

> The Confederation of Human Worlds in the 25th century has established its capital city at Fargo, North Dakota which has grown into a large metropolis with many skyscrapers and government buildings. The military headquarters of the Confederation in Fargo, North Dakota is called the Heptagon. There is a space navy, an army with air force capability (transported aboard space navy spaceships to whatever planet they are ordered to), and a Marine Corps. Humans have colonized numerous worlds out to several hundred light years but are starting to come into conflict with surrounding extraterrestrials.

One of the primary characters is Staff Sergeant Charlie Bass.

Summary of the first book, *[First to Fight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/662671.First_to_Fight)*:

> Stranded in a hellish alien desert, stripped of their strategic systems, quick reaction force, and supporting arms, and carrying only a day's water ration, Marine Staff Sergeant Charlie Bass and his seven-man team faced a grim future seventy-five light-years from home. The only thing between his Marines and safety was eighty-five miles of uncharted, waterless terrain and two thousand bloodthirsty savages with state-of-the-art weapons in their hands and murder on their minds.

Found by searching for *book series marines "sgt bass"*

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: FuzzyBoots I did try google searches, but none of mine came up with the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @John: You never know what's going to match up. It usually takes me 2-3 searches, looking at the first few pages of results, before I find an answer, if I do.

Comment: FuzzyBoots Yes, I usually go at least 5-6 pages.  The trick is getting the correct keywords.